# Prestashop: import images from antother site

Tags: image, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I developed an utility to import products from a web service which executes under a cron command. I have an issue with images, I don't know what I have to do with them, the service gives me an image url which I can download to my server and update in my prestashop database this product image, but it's not showing it, I guess I must run some Prestashop command or generate thumbnails or similar?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prestashop has a good documentation about handling image via webservice.

Have you checked this?

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+9+-+Image+management